# The Apollo error doesn't contain the payload

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Catching server errors on the client side. I'm passing an object with the Apollo error from which I read what went wrong. I've been using this approach throughout the project and it works fine, but for some reason in this particular instance, it doesn't. I'm not doing anything differently, but the payload just isn't there.

Server code:

```
const { UserInputError } = require('apollo-server-express');

const commentResolver = {
  Mutation: {
    createComment: async (_, { postID, body }, context) => {
      const user = checkAuth(context);
      // empty error object I fill with messages and pass it with the error
      const errors = {};

      try {
        if (body.trim() === '') {
          errors.body = 'Comments must not be empty';
          throw new UserInputError('Empty comment', { errors });
        }
      // ...more code
```

Client code:

```
const [submitComment] = useMutation(CREATE_COMMENT, {
    variables: {
      postID,
      body: comment,
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);   // prints undefined
      setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    },
```

What I get when printing just the err object:
[no errors field in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N33pB.png)

Comment: probably you're looking for custom error (or fomratter, see docs) ... check this specific error source if it can pass additional variables, probably it is sepcialised to use only field pointing params

Comment: Docs say it allows "arbitrary fields to the error's extensions object to provide additional context to the client" and the code they provide is identical to this. :|

Comment: notice, your response doesn't contain `"code": "BAD_USER_INPUT"` ... other configured error processing/masking/formatting ? ... check specific error IMPLEMENTATION/source code, not source of an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the errors were being thrown inside a try/catch block that catches and throws a generic nodejs error instead of an apollo error. So changing the error type from `Error` to `ApolloError` did the trick.

```
try {
  // ...code 
} catch {
  throw new ApolloError('InputValidationError', 'INVALID_INPUT', {
      errors,
    });
}
```

Another method that works is to simply throw the errors outside the block.

Comment: *'code they provide is identical to this'* ;)

Comment: 'Identical' indeed :p